# LibVLCSharp on .net core looking for option to append stream to existing file

Tags: libvlcsharp

I'm using LibVLCSharp with videoLAN.LibVLC.Windows on .net core 3.1 console app.  I'm recording a http m3u stream to local file.  Also, I want to append to existing file.  I've tried `this.CurrentMedia.AddOption(":sout-file-append");` without success.  It keeps overriding file.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
media.AddOption(":no-sout-file-overwrite");
media.AddOption(":sout-file-append");
```